# Event not working in dynamic html in angular2

Tags: html, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Want to append the dynamic generated html in a DOM, its appending successfully in a DOM but none of the function is working like click etc.

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.sideBarData += '<li class="sidebar-toggler-wrapper hide" >' +
          '<div class="sidebar-toggler" > </div>' +
          '</li>' +
          '<li class="sidebar-search-wrapper"></li>';
        this.sideBarData += '<li class="nav-item start">' +
          '<a class="nav-link home name" (click)="HomeButton(event)">' +
          '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>' +
          '<span class="title">Home</span>' +
          '</a>' +
          '</li>';
        this.getJSONService.getData()
          .subscribe(response => {
            var value=response.datas
            if (value.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                if (value[i].state)
                {
                    this.sideBarData += '<li class="nav-item" >' +
                            '<a (click)="parentNav($event)" routerLink="/' + value[i].state + '" class="nav-link nav-toggle ' + value[i].key + '" >' +
                            '<i class="fa fa-' + value[i].label_Icon + '"></i>' +
                            '<span class="title">' + value[i].label + '</span>';
                    if (this.checkDataExist(value[i]))
                    {
                       var data1 = this.data(value[i]);
                    }        
                    this.sideBarData += '</a></li>';
                } else
                {
                    this.sideBarData += '<li class="nav-item" >' +
                            '<a  class="nav-link nav-toggle ' + value[i].key + '" (click)="parentNav($event)">' +
                            '<i class="fa fa-' + value[i].label_Icon + '"></i>' +
                            '<span class="title">' + value[i].label + '</span>';
                    if (this.checkDataExist(value[i]))
                    {
                       var data1 = this.data(value[i].data);
                    } 
                    this.sideBarData += '</a></li>';
                    this.sidebarChild.element.nativeElement.innerHTML=this.sideBarData
                }
              }
            }
          })                        
      }
```

Data is appending in DOM but no any event call is working..

Can you please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting ***html*** in ***DOM*** directly by yourself isn't the right way of doing things in ***Angular***.
The right way is to split your code into ***Components***, where each Component should have it's own responsibilaty (S in S.O.L.I.D.).

And for this kind of ***interactivaty*** (showing/hiding, styling) you should use: *ngIf*, *ngSwitch*, *ngClass* in your templates.