# Html controls not working with angular 2 agter window.print()

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

 var printContents = document.getElementById('printSection').innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();

 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

In above code I am trying to print content of one div that is 'printSection' and its printing fine but when i reload the originalContents to document.body.innerHTML the html file shows as expected but the controls dosent work, ie clicking on any control not work

Comment: are you using it in angular2?

Comment: yes angular 2 typescript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786555/event-not-working-in-dynamic-html-in-angular2 check this link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053067/click-event-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html-angular-2 also this

Comment: I faced same issue, resolve it by using "location.reload(); " after window.printf(). but i don't think so this is the best way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, Both of you..!!